# Validate form data sent to API?

Tags: json, flask-restful

I have a front-end form sending me the form data in JSON format to the back-end API. The API is based on flask-restful library. There is data validation being done in the front-end, but I've been told to also validate the data in the back-end.

Is back-end validation of this sort even required? If so, then what is the best way to validate the data sent from this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you need to validate data on the backend as well. That's because by-passing front-end validation is very easy. You have to always validate on the backend side.

For validating the data on the backend, today's frameworks such as `django` and `DRF` provide a host of facilities. In `Django` you will have Django forms and in `DRF` you will have `serializers`.

They come equipped with some robust basic validations which you can further extend to your needs.